# Failing to install Spidermonkey because of autoconf

Tags: couchdb, autoconf, homebrew, spidermonkey

Trying to install Spidermonkey following this guide; 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_only_SpiderMonkey#Easy_build
I'm supposed to follow these steps:

```
    cd js/src
    autoconf-2.13
    ./configure
    make
```

As I don't have autoconf, I'm trying to get that following another mozilla tutorial as seen below:

> As of December 2011, Homebrew does not have a recipe for autoconf
>   2.13, but one can be obtained here. Install the file in /usr/local/Library/Formula and then:
>
> $ brew install autoconf213

Which installs autoconf. But when running `autoconf-2.13` the terminal just outputs `-bash: autoconf-2.13: command not found`

environment: OSX 10.7.2

Been banging my head against this problem for many hours now and can't seem to get around it, which unfortunatly ruins my chances of getting couchdb to run on my computer. 
Any ideas for a solution?

Comment: What error do you get for 'brew install spidermonkey'?

Comment: infact, no error, infact, the terminal doesn't output anything at all.

Answer (score 4):

The Homebrew formula provided in that link installs autoconf with --program-suffix=213, which means the installed binaries will be autoconf213, autoheader213, autoupdate213, etc.

Try:

```
$ cd js/src
$ autoconf213
$ ./configure
$ make
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy enough to install autoconf from source.  2.13 is ancient, but still available at ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/

Grab the 2.13 tarball from there, unpack it, cd into the toplevel and run:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME && make && make install
```

You should then be able to cd into js/src and run

```
$ $HOME/bin autoconf
```

Answer (score 0):

I think should try:
 `autoconf2.13`